# Show that the set of even functions in $C[-1,1]$ is a proper closed subalgebra of $C[-1,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

I know that an algebra is a vector space $A$ on which a multiplication is defined $(f,g)\mapsto fg$ (from $A\times A$ into $A$) satisfying:

i) $(fg) = f(gh)$, for all $f,g \in A$;

ii) $f(g + h) = fg + fh, (f + g)h = fh + gh$, for all $f,g,h \in A$;

iii) $\alpha(fg) = (\alpha f)g = f(\alpha g)$, for all scalars $\alpha$ and all $f,g \in A$.

**Question:** How do I show that the set of even functions in $C[-1,1]$ is a proper closed subalgebra of $C[-1,1]$? Should I show that every subset of even function in $C[-1,1]$ satisfies all the properties listed above, and is closed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have show that the sum, product, multiplication by a scalar, and limits of even continuous functions are even continuous functions.

And, to show that it is a *proper* subalgebra, you need to exhibit a function $f\in C[-1,1]$ that is not even.

Comment: Technically speaking, the word "proper" also must be justified, by showing that not all continuous functions are even...

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I didn't think about mentioning that, but I'll include it in the answer.